# Next.jsのブログkatexで書かれた数式を表示したい。

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, next.js

mdファイルを取り扱うのに `remark` を使用しているので `remark-math` というものをドキュメントに沿ってインストールしたんですが、今で `import` でモジュールを取り込んできたのに `require` で読み込んでいてNext.jsではこのようなモジュールの取り込み方は出来るのでしょうか？ 一応ドキュメント通り `require` で試してみたのですが、エラーが出ます。

見て頂けないでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

```
npm install remark-math rehype-katex
```

#### 使い方

```
const vfile = require('to-vfile')
const unified = require('unified')
const markdown = require('remark-parse')
const math = require('remark-math')
const remark2rehype = require('remark-rehype')
const katex = require('rehype-katex')
const stringify = require('rehype-stringify')

unified()
  .use(markdown)
  .use(math)
  .use(remark2rehype)
  .use(katex)
  .use(stringify)
  .process(vfile.readSync('example.md'), function (err, file) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(String(file))
  })
```

#### 追記

エラーは解決しました。
実際に自分の環境に必要だったのは下記の2つのモジュールで `import` で読み込む事ができました。

```
import math from 'remark-math'
import katex from 'rehype-katex'

export async function getHtmlContent(article: Article) {
  const processedContent = await remark()
    .use(html)
    .use(math)
    .use(katex)
    .use(prism)
    .process(article.content)
  const contentHtml = processedContent.toString()
  return {
    ...article,
    content: contentHtml
  }
}
```

それでクラスが付与されたHTMLを生成する事ができたんですが、CSSが上手く当てられません。

```
<div class="math math-display">\log_a{b} = \frac{\log_c{b}}{\log_c{a}}</div>
```

[ここ](https://blog.zenpachi.dev/posts/nextjs-blog-02/)のサイトを参考に
`_app.js` で `import 'katex/dist/katex.min.css'`を読み込んだのですが上手く行きませんでした。
ファイルの中身を見ると `math math-display` に関する記述は見られなかったので別のCSSが必要な気がします。

#### 参照

https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-math

Comment: エラーの内容を [edit] して追記いただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: FYI: https://book.yyts.org/features/import-export-require#typescriptdeha

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。質問を追記しました。

Answer (score 0):

`remark-html-katex`を使用する事で上手く動作しました。